# Execute method in class A after class B has completed an asynchronous operation

Tags: android, android-volley

I have 3 classes: LogIn, LogicController and WebService.

LogIn is an Activity that, by pressing a button, executes a static LogicController method which, in turn, executes a static method in WebService. WebService makes a request to the server using JsonObjectRequest. I need that interaction to represent the MVC model (a school work requires it), and I could not do it without static methods, since I could not "serialize" LogicController to pass as a variable to LogIn.

The problem is that I can not get LogIn to wait for WebService to complete its work before continuing, and I need that to use a parameter returned by it.

LogIn class:

```
public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txtUsr;
    EditText txtPass;
    Button btnLogIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        txtUsr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsr);
        txtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);

        btnLogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIS);
        btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                logInWebService();
            }
        });
    }

    private void logInWebService() {
        String usr = txtUsr.getText().toString();
        String pass = txtPass.getText().toString();

        boolean result;
        result = LogicController.logInWebService(this, usr, pass);

        if(result){
            //doSomething in response to the result
            //need to execute this after logInWebService is done
        }
    }
}
```

LogicController class:

```
public class LogicController extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebService myWebService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myWebService = new WebService(1);
    }

    public static boolean logInWebService(Context context, String usr, String pass){
        boolean result = WebService.logInWebService(context, usr, pass);
        return result;
    }
}
```

WebService class:

```
    public class WebService {
    private static boolean result;

    public WebService(int idGestor) {
        this.idGestor = idGestor;
    }

    public static boolean logInWebService(Context context, final String usr, final String pass) {
        String url = "https://webpage.myPhpWS.php?"+"idusr="+usr+"&pass="+pass;
        result = false

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if(someOperation){
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error"+error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        return result; //this is the final result needed
    }
}
```

- I use nested classes since the WebService class makes several requests, and I must be able to handle them separately. I would prefer, if possible, not to add classes to this scheme.
- I could not find a thread that touched on this specific topic.
- Any help would be useful, even if I'm having a bad approach from the beginning.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a callback interface and pass it as a parameter to the `LogicController.logInWebService(this, usr, pass,callback);`.

1- create interface `ResultCallback`

```
interface ResultCallback {

void on success();
void onFailure();
   }
```

2- pass it to the `logInWebService`

```
 //show progress dialog before making the request
 LogicController.logInWebService(this, usr, pass,new ResultCallback (){

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    //hide progress and show success message
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                    //hide progress and show error
                }
            }
    );
```

3- then modify your method `logInWebService()`

```
 public static boolean logInWebService(Context context, final String usr, final String pass,ResultCallback callback) {
    String url = "https://webpage.myPhpWS.php?"+"idusr="+usr+"&pass="+pass;
    result = false

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        callback.onSuccess(); //you can pass sth to this method
            if(someOperation){
                result = true;
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Error"+error.getMessage());
             callback.onSuccess();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    return result; //remove this and return void instead.
}
```

a better approach is to use  [Rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) observables.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer. First I found it more complex, but then understood it. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i had the same problem, i just solved it with ObservableInteger , just declare it

```
private ObservableInteger mObsInt;
```

then in onCreate setup a listener

```
 //Listener
        mObsInt = new ObservableInteger();
        mObsInt.set(0);

        mObsInt.setOnIntegerChangeListener(new OnIntegerChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onIntegerChanged(int newValue)
            {
                if (mObsInt.get()==1)
                    Log.e("Downloads"," mObsInt 1");
                Log.e("Download1"," Finished first process ");
                if (mObsInt.get()==2){
                    Log.e("Downloads"," mObsInt 2");
                    Log.e("Download2"," Finished second process ");
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(LoginActivity.this, Principal.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

and then just do this (after a process has finished)

```
mObsInt.set(mObsInt.get()+1);
```

so it will count, if the first thing finish obsInt will be 1 , and when the second one finish, obsInt will be 2, so after obsInt == 2 , you can move on to the other activity or process you need

happy coding !

Comment: Thanks for your response! I thinks it's a good approach, but I still have two questions about it: **1)** Is this method still available and not deprecated? Because I couldn't find a way to declare an attribute with "private ObservableInt mObsInt". Is there some imports needed for it? I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1, and says: Cannot resolve symbol 'ObservableInt'. **2)** I didn't understand the way to access the "Observable" variable from the other class, without passing it as a parameter. Could you please clarify it?